# Querying coastal roads using overpass turbo

Tags: openstreetmap, spatial-query, overpass-turbo

Is it possible to query [overpass turbo](https://overpass-turbo.eu/) using some kind spatial filter?  I would like to download "coastal" roads data, coastal currently being defined as within 0.20 km from the coast.

The end goal is to have this data globally.  It's not feasible to do country-by-country using the [Geofabrik Downloads](http://download.geofabrik.de/index.html) since I would then have to bring into GIS and run some type of clip or select-by-location that would likely take forever or just crash my machine.

Comment: This is not feasible via overpass turbo. You need a country extract or even a full planet file and import the data in some GIS database.

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought but assuming I have a smaller area, is there a way to query overpass for highway features within a certain distance of coasts?  I know coastline is a map feature: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag%3Anatural%3Dcoastline

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following query for smaller areas. As the around filter is still rather inefficient, you will probably see timeouts on larger areas. It is possible that your IP address may be temporarily blocked due to excessive use of resources.

```
[bbox:{{bbox}}];
way[natural=coastline];
way(around:200)[highway];
(._;>;);
out meta;
```